# Calling variables outside couchdb function?

Tags: node.js, couchdb, nowjs-sockets, cradle

I'm having alot of trouble getting couchdb's response handlers to do anything useful with node.js and now.js. My aim is to call back to a client or group with certain information that's been found and also sent from a client.

```
everyone.now.login = function(){
var username = this.now.lusername;
var password = this.now.lpassword;
var test;
db.get(this.now.lusername, function (err, doc, test, username) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(+ username + " doesn't exist!");

    } else  {
        console.log('Found user!');
        console.log(doc);
        test = 1;
   }
    });
    console.log(test);
}
```

I'm using test as an example here. I declare it outside db.get, assign a value inside to feed back but when console.log is run outside  it doesn't have a value.

Am I simply not getting it or is something wrong?

(I do release I can use doc.(whatever value) but there is a particular variable i wanted to pass on back to the client outside of this call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `test` variable will not have a value in the `console.log` because the CouchDB response has not arrived yet. Your login function executes the following steps.

1. Set some variables (`username`, `password`, and `test` is undefined)
2. Begin a CouchDB fetch (for `this.now.lusername`) with a function assigned to run when it is complete
3. Run `console.log(test)` which is still undefined
4. The CouchDB response completes, and your function from step 2 runs

What I do for things like this is use function calls.

```
everyone.now.login = function(){
  var username = this.now.lusername;
  var password = this.now.lpassword;

  db.get(this.now.lusername, function (err, doc, test, username) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(+ username + " doesn't exist!");

    } else  {
        console.log('Found user!');
        console.log(doc);
        login_complete(doc);
   }
  });

  function login_complete(doc) {
    console.log('The login finished! Doc is ' + doc)
  }
}
```

This way the code still **looks** correct (the "story" of the code mostly flows from top to bottom), but it also **executes** correctly (the `login_complete()` function runs only after the login is actually complete).